# Superscript horizontal alignment on flipped integral symbol

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, math-operators, superscripts, integral

I'm trying to define a command in latex that gives me a flipped integral symbol as I haven't been able to find it in any existing package.
So far this is my attempt:

```
\newcommand{\cocoendtni}{\operatorname{\vphantom{\sum}\mathchoice
    {\reflectbox{$\displaystyle \int$}}
    {\reflectbox{$\int$}}
    {\reflectbox{$\scriptstyle \int$}}
    {\reflectbox{$\scriptscriptstyle \int$}}}}
```

This has the problem that superscripts are not aligned to the integral sign itself, but its rightmost part.
The usual integral sign does not have this problem with subscripts.

How can I align the superscripts horizontally? If this symbol already exists somewhere or you see other issues with my definition I'd be glad to hear about them of course!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\cocoendtni}{e{_^}}{%
  \mathop{\mathpalette\cocoendtni@{{#1}{#2}}}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\cocoendtni@}{mm}{%
  \cocoendtni@@#1#2%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\cocoendtni@@}{mmm}{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1\int$}%
  \reflectbox{\usebox\z@}%
  \IfValueT{#2}{% subscript
    _{#2}%
  }%
  \IfValueT{#3}{% superscript
    ^{\kern-\ifx#1\displaystyle0.5\else0.4\fi\wd\z@#3}%
  }%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
\cocoendtni_a^b
\]
\begin{center}
$\cocoendtni_a^b$\\
$\scriptstyle\cocoendtni_a^b$\\
$\scriptscriptstyle\cocoendtni_a^b$
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

The superscript is added with some amount of backspacing, so it goes nearer the integral sign.

[image]

Comment: Looks perfect, thank you!